# How to trigger MouseDown via PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I tried:

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent("mousedown", true, true);
jQuery('.left-rail-facets .facet-list .facet.CS .suggestion[data-value="B"] a')[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

but it just fails to trigger the action on the site. 
no error returned.

Comment: Please, show how a broader sample of your code (you could be using this sample in not the right place). Also: are you absolutely positive the element exists at the time of running this code? Have you checked in code/ with screenshot? Also: it's useful to state the PhantomJS version and environment you use in the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you programmatically trigger a click on a DOM element with a "mousedown" event. To answer your question, you need to have two things in your source code:

> event listeners to detect the clicks

and

> commas between your multiple selectors in your jQuery line.

Please run the snippet below, which shows the modified jQuery line and the listeners running correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // You must have event listeners to see if anything is actually happening. For example, here I will add only a listener to the first element:
      jQuery(".left-rail-facets")[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        jQuery(".left-rail-facets")[0].innerHTML = "I have received a click.";
      }, false);
      // Now here is the code from your question. Please see how I have commas instead of spaces in my jQuery selector:
      var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
     clickEvent.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);
      jQuery('.left-rail-facets,.facet-list,.facet.CS,.suggestion[data-value="B"],a')[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>I am a Webpage</h1>

  <p class="left-rail-facets">I have not received a click.</p>
  <p class="facet-list">I have not received a click.</p>
  <facet class="CS">I have not received a click.</facet>
  <p class="suggestion" data-value="B">I have not received a click.</p>
  <a href="url">I have not received a click.</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the document.createEvent and event.initMouseEvent:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.left-rail-facets .facet-list .facet.CS .suggestion[data-value="B"] a');
//or var element = jQuery('.left-rail-facets .facet-list .facet.CS .suggestion[data-value="B"] a')[0];
var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
mouseEvent.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 0, elementRect.left, elementRect.top);
```